# Mobilefirst worklightconsole and liberty and virtual host

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

For security reason I want to run mobileapps and worklightconsole on separate IP ports. But when I add virtual hosts and IP ports in the liberty configuration worklightconsole listen on all the ports. 
Is it possible to define a virtual host configuration on the console war ? can I add ibm-web-bnd.xml to the .WAR or is another way to fix this problem ?

enviroment:
mobilefirst 7.1
was liberty 8.5.5.7

Answer (score 1):

IBM MobileFirst Platform Foundation does not support virtual host in Liberty. This is due to the provided console.war which requires changes in its web.xml, and the changes are not compatible with WAS and Tomcat. Your manual changes done to this will be lost the next time an iFix is installed.

Additionally, per this user documentation topic: 
https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/cwlp_virtual_hosts.html

You need to have a ibm-web-bnd.xml in the .war file and definif the virtual hosts.
Also in tWAS the mapping of the virtual host is done outside the war file.

In short, it is not supported...